# How can I show only some attribute elements in GoodData filter dropdowns?

Tags: gooddata

I know metrics and useAvailable clause in dashboard filter definition can be used to limit what the user sees in the filter dropdown. How do I properly define the filtering metric and what should the filter definition look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

filtering metric:
SELECT SUM (1) WHERE ATTRIBUTE IN (VALUE1,VALUE2,...,VALUE N)